# XCode 8 missing Code Signing Identity Debug

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

Please help me to get the Code Signing Identity > Debug options in my target setting. I remember deleting something related accidentally and now I cannot see how to put that setting back and I need it to test my app on a device.

*I'm using XCode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)*

Here's my Build Settings :

[image: build settings]

Comment: Hover you mouse cursor over `Code Signing Identity` then (+) sign apears. Then click and add the debug option from the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `Debug` target? At the picture you shared, there's no Debug target!
You can't run a release target directly on you device.

If you are missing the `Debug` target, you'll have to create it

[image: Creating a Target on Xcode]


When you see the `Debug` target, make sure to use `Automatic` and `iOS Developer`

If you have issues with `Provisioning Profiles`, make to sure to update it.

[image]